# SugarCRM on Bluemix

Tags: php, web, cloud, sugarcrm, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy SugarCRM community version on Bluemix. I'm using PHP runtime, I forked out the project from the git repository of SugarCRM community and I bound a mySQL service to the application.

The application runs and came out with the standard installation page of sugarcrm, as I proceed, the screen shows me this error:

> Functions associated with the Multibyte Strings PHP extension
>   (mbstring) that are needed by the Sugar application were not found.
>
> **MB String Module**
>
> **Generally, the mbstring module is not enabled by default in PHP and must be activated with --enable-mbstring when the PHP binary is built.
>   Please refer to your PHP Manual for more information on how to enable
>   mbstring support. Location of your PHP configuration file (php.ini):
>   /home/vcap/app/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/php/php.ini**

I looked through the installation guide of SugarCRM, it seems like I have to go to the root directory of the server to modify php.ini. But I can't find any way to do that since Bluemix is a PaaS. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.  It allows you easily include php extensions that you need.  In this case you need `mbstring`.

Create a file called `.bp-config/options.json` in the root of your app.

Set the variable `PHP_EXTENSIONS` with a value of `mbstring`.  Below is an example file.

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": "mbstring"
}
```

Push your app with the command `cf push appname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git`.

Additionally check out this page on how you do customer things/extensions with the PHP buildpack. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md